# Swig : typemap(in) VS typemap(out) : differences

Tags: java, c++, c, wrapper, swig

Only few days were given to me to deal with Swig and to wrap nice C specific creatures.

I'm reading the Swig documentation for wrapping into Java, that I can't judge if it is not good enough or if I'm stupid enough, finally maybe because I'm Java enough, but not C/C++ enough. So, pity a Java developer that I am.

**First :**

What is the difference between :

1. typemap(in) and typemap(out)?
2. typemap(in) and typemap(directorin)?

I would appreciate clear explainations ( and that fits my modest intelligence) such as :

- if you have this in C/C++ and you want to get this in Java, use this in Swig...
- using $input would mean in typemap(in)..., when $result would mean ..., when $1, $2, .. would mean...
- using $result would mean in typemap(out), when $input would mean ..., when $1, $2, .. would mean...
- using $result would mean in typemap(directorin), when $input would mean ..., when $1, $2, .. would mean...

**Second :**

Can you please give an example to wrap a structure in C?